# AutoComplete dropdown immediately disappears

Tags: asp.net-ajax, ajaxcontroltoolkit

Using AutoCompleExtender from the Ajax Control Toolkit, if MinimumPrefixLength=0 and CompletionInterval=100, and you click slowly on the textbox (as in leave >100ms between pressing and releasing the mouse button), the dropdown appears and then immediately disappears.

The sample website has MinimumPrefixLength=0 and CompletionInterval=1000 so to see the same effect you don't see the same effect.

(Raised as http://ajaxcontroltoolkit.codeplex.com/workitem/26996)

(Reproduced in IE7 and FF4)

(Updated 24/08/11 with information about being related to CompletionInterval)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My current workaround is to set CompletionInterval=400. Although this makes it less responsive, it seems a fair compromise between the time it take to press a mouse button and the time the user expects to wait for suggestions.